# Is it incorrect to place the adverb after the verb? "Handsomely win" v. "Win handsomely"

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis, grammaticality

I have seen both forms in usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct. Sometimes it sounds fine in both places. Bold if before, italics if after:

> He **quickly** put on his shoes and left.
>
> He put on his shoes *quickly* and left.
>
> I ate *greedily* until my stomach **literally** exploded. I've been in the hospital for a few days trying to get it sewn back together.

The use of 'literally' here would sound strange if it were after the verb: "my stomach exploded *literally*". That changes the meaning, actually, from one of "it actually exploded" to "it exploded in a fashion related to letters/literature".